# change column ordering of bootstrap grid system

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid, media-queries

I want to change the default behaviour of the bootstrap grid system. I'm using the following lines of codes to display two columns in my page:

```
<div class="col-md-8" id="one"> 
...
</div>

<div class="col-md-4" id="two">
...
</div>
```

When the screen size is too small to display both columns next to each other bootstrap positions the `div one` above `div two`. I want to invert this behaviour so that it positions `div two` above `div one`. However if it is enough space for both columns the default behaviour should stay the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order of the `<div>`'s such that `two` comes first to make the order on the small screen correct. Then use `col-md-push-8` and `col-md-pull-4` to push and pull the `two` and `one` columns into the correct order on larger screens.

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-md-4 col-md-push-8">two</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-pull-4">one</div>
```

See http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering for some background information on column ordering

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake I'm using col-md-4 and col-md-8. But your solution just works fine. Thank you very much.